# Why does color disappear completely from my graphic once I export it as .svg

Tags: color, svg, layers, export

I`m still a beginner on GravitDesigner but created several vector icons already. One strange thing happened already several times: I create a new icon with different shapes and compound paths with different color fills.

[image: how it looks before export]

Once I export it as an .svg and use it within another document such as a presentation, all the color has disappeared.

When I open the file in GravitDesigner again, I see that GravitDesigner has created endless different layers (rectangles, groups, rectangle again, compound paths...) and nested the color filled paths within it.

[image: when I open the svg again]

The color appears back once I delete the unneccesary layers but disappears in the .svg as soon as I export the file again.

Any idea how I can avoid that?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi Veronika, welcome to GD.SE. You should include in your question the tag of the program you use to create this icon. It would also be good to add the .svg code.

Comment: Hey Danielillo, thanks a lot - good points!

Answer (score 2):

After having a quick look at the GravitDesigner user documentation, it would seem there is a special option to *preserve editing capabilities for SVG files* when exporting an SVG and opening it again in GravitDesigner. Make sure you have checked that option when exporting.

Here's the relevant image and quote from the Import-Export page.

[image]

> 5. Preserve editing capabilities for SVG files: This will ensure that SVGs exported from Gravit can be fully edited if imported back to Gravit, while retaining full fidelity. It is similar to saving as a .gvdesign file, but embedded inside the SVG.

Source: https://documentation.designer.io/import-export/export/

If the above doesn't solve your problem, you might need to reach out to the developers for support.  There's a support forum here https://discuss.gravit.io/t/please-contact-our-support-team/7564